# RakNet for iOS on Xamarin

Tags: ios, networking, xamarin

I have developed a Windows game that uses RakNet.

Now I'm interested in porting it over to iOS using Xamarin but I can not find any pre-compiled RakNet library for use.

Does anyone know or have any info on how to get RakNet to work with Xamarin for iOS?

Note:
Please do not suggest any alternative development environments such as Unity. I am very well aware of other development environments, but I need to take this approach instead of switching to a different environment altogether.

Comment: Seeing as it is C++ and compiles to a native lib, does it have a C interface? If so then it's pretty easy to access, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/ has details on how to do it.

Comment: Just to be sure, how do I know if it has a C interface? I've never worked with C or C++ before.